# Reversing the Order of Integration and Summation

Tags: calculus, integration, summation

I am trying to understand when we can interchange the order of Integration and Summation. I am increasingly encountering Integrals; some of which are being solved by interchanging the order of Summation and  Integration, and some which cannot (for no given reason) be solved using this.
Despite looking at a variety of sites, I was unable to understand when we can do so. 
$$$$
I came up with the following two requirements here on MSE:$$$$
If$f_n(x)\ge 0$ for all $x,n$
$$\sum \int f_n(x) \, dx = \int \sum f_n(x) \,dx$$
Also if $\sum \int |f_n| < \infty$ or $\int \sum |f_n| < \infty$, then 
$$\int \sum f_n = \sum \int f_n$$

I would be grateful if somebody could  please explain this to me. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: If I recall correctly, then if the sum of the integral converges, then the integral of the sum converges to the same value and vice versa. This is an application of Fubini's theorem.

Comment: You are presumably integrating over $x$ and summing over $n$

Comment: Regarding the notation $f_n(x)$, I imagine $n$ is a summation index. Not sure about swapping the sum and integral in $\int g(x) \sum f(x) dx$. Better wait for someone more knowledgeable to answer. Although, if you use the $f_n(x)$ notation properly, then swapping the sum and the integral shouldn't be a problem assuming it can be done without $g(x)$ in the expression.

Comment: If you don't like $f_n(x)$, you can write $f(n,x)$. It means the same thing. We tend to separate $n$ and $x$ for various reasons (mainly so that we can conveniently isolate the function $g(x)=f(n,x)$ for a fixed $n$, by simply writing $f_n$).

Comment: If you don't understand what $f_n(x)$ means, then could you give us an _example_ of an expression involving $\sum\int$ or $\int\sum$ about which you have questions? I'm having trouble understanding what you could be asking about if you don't understand what $f_n(x)$ means. If you have $\int$ there's a "$dx$" in there somewhere -- a variable with respect to which you're integrating.  And if you have $\sum$ the you must have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ or the like, with the index called $n$. There's an $x$ and there's an $n$; otherwise you haven't got an integral and a sum. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @BetterWorld A notational correction: the summation sign should be before any use of the variable $n$. So you might write $\int_1^0 \sum_{n=0}^\infty t^{2n} \ln(t) dt$. You could also write $\int_1^0 \ln(t) \sum_{n=0}^\infty t^{2n} dt$. But you could never have the variable $n$ before the sum that introduces $n$.

Comment: @BetterWorld Really, the best answer to your question is going to be found in a "real analysis" text which covers measure theory, not an advanced calculus text. The "advanced calculus" criteria are generally based on uniform convergence, which is too restrictive for most applications.

Comment: @BetterWorld You started with $\int_1^0 \ln(t) \sum_{n=0}^\infty t^{2n} dt$. When you interchange the sum and integral you get $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_1^0 t^{2n} \ln(t) dt$. I think this uniform convergence approach actually does work in your case, although it's not a completely trivial matter to show. For $t \in (\delta,1-\delta)$ it is not hard to see (the geometric series converges uniformly and $\ln$ is bounded on such an interval). But it takes some work to conclude that there is uniform convergence on $[0,1]$. By contrast monotone convergence gives you the result essentially for free.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The more general question is about interchanging *limits* and integration. With infinite sums, this is a special case, because by definition $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x) = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N f_n(x)$. So because one can always interchange finite sums and integration, the only question is about interchanging the limit and the integration.

Writing what I just said in symbols, we want conditions such that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_X f_n(x) dx = \int_X \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x) dx.$$

Expanding the definition:

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \int_X f_n(x) dx = \int_X \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N f_n(x) dx.$$

Now one interchange is free:

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \int_X f_n(x) dx = \lim_{N \to \infty} \int_X \sum_{n=1}^N f_n(x) dx.$$

The issue is with the last interchange, which is what most of the rest of this answer is about.

The most general result of this type is the Vitali convergence theorem. It says that if $f_n$ is a sequence of measurable functions, $f_n \to f$ pointwise, $f_n$ is uniformly integrable, and $f_n$ is tight, then $\int_X f_n(x) dx \to \int_X f(x) dx.$ (Here $X$ is the set over which we integrate.) You can look up the formal definitions of "uniformly integrable" and "tight" yourself. Roughly speaking they mean that you cannot "compress mass into a point" and that you can't "move mass to infinity". These intuitions are illustrated by the failure of the conclusion of the theorem for the sequences $f_n(x)=\begin{cases} n & x \in [0,1/n] \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$ on $[0,1]$ and $g_n(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & x \in [n,n+1] \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$ on the whole line.

The Vitali convergence theorem is general but it is not convenient. The result with perhaps the best balance between generality and convenience to check is the dominated convergence theorem. This says that if $f_n \to f$ pointwise and there is a fixed integrable function $g$ such that $|f_n(x)| \leq g(x)$ for all $n$ and $x$, then $\int_X f_n(x) dx \to \int_X f(x) dx.$

One relatively basic result is the monotone convergence theorem, which says that if $f_n$ is an increasing sequence of nonnegative functions and $f_n \to f$ pointwise, then $\int_X f_n(x) dx \to \int_X f(x) dx$. In particular this holds whether or not $f$ is actually integrable (if it isn't, then the limit of the integrals is $+\infty$). This is also applicable to the case when $f_n$ are nonpositive and decrease to $f$ (this is easy to prove, since $\int_X -g(x) dx = -\int_X g(x) dx$). This is useful for summation, because if $f_n(x) \geq 0$ then $g_N(x)=\sum_{n=1}^N f_n(x)$ is an increasing sequence of nonnegative functions.

Finally in the special case of interchanging summation and integration, one can apply the abstract version of the Fubini-Tonelli theorem. This is because summation can be identified as integration with respect to the counting measure. As a result, if either

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_X |f_n(x)| dx < \infty$$

or

$$\int_X \sum_{n=1}^\infty |f_n(x)| dx < \infty$$

then one may interchange summation and integration. (This requires a hypothesis about $X$; because this holds for the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$, I won't state it, since this is already a more advanced writeup than you wanted.)

Comment: @BetterWorld $X$ can be $\mathbb{R}$; usually we write $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ instead of $\int_{\mathbb{R}}$.

Comment: @BetterWorld The limits being infinite doesn't matter. (Again, there *is* a condition in the last result, which is that the space $X$ has to be "$\sigma$-finite", but $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ are $\sigma$-finite, so that's not an obstacle for your purposes). As for your second question, everything works out if you use different indices. You can even sum over the whole set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ and it works out the same.

Comment: I am afraid that you have wasted a lot of your time writeing down this nice answers: as you can see, the OP wasn't asking about the subtle problem of switching limits with integrals, he was asking about what $f_n (x)$ means...

Comment: @BetterWorld Sure, that's just a special case.

Comment: @Ian, Could you address the cases the integral is $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} $ and the case of indefinite integral? Namely not only in the contxt of measures. Thank You.

Comment: @Royi The question makes no sense for indefinite integrals; indefinite integrals should be thought of as $\int_a^x f(y) dy$ for almost all purposes except strict calculation. Improper Riemann integration on the other hand has very few "good theorems" in this sense because changing the manner in which you approach your limits of integration can change the result. The best way I can adapt this to Riemann integration is to say that if all the relevant integrals of $|f_n|$ and $|f|$ are finite then the same result goes through.