# Example where change of integration and sum order matters

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I would like a simple example of a series of measurable functions $(f_n)$ where
the sum of the integrals of $(f_n)$ does not equal the integral of the sum of $(f_n)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n\in\mathbb N$, define$$\begin{array}{rccc}g_n\colon&[0,1]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}2n^2x&\text{ if }x<\frac1{2n}\\2n-2n^2x&\text{ if }x\in\left[\frac1{2n},\frac1n\right]\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$Then $(g_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges pointwise to the null function, but $\int_0^1g_n(x)\,\mathrm dx=\frac12$, for each $n\in\mathbb N$.

Now, you can convert this example into a series: just take $f_1=g_1$ and, if $n>1$, $f_n=g_n-g_{n-1}$.

Comment: Could you please add  some hypothesis which guarentee the change of sum and integral valid

Comment: @CloudJR Take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334907/reversing-the-order-of-integration-and-summation).

Comment: Is uniform convergence of the series a sufficient condition to change integral and sum? Btw I checked that question  it doesn't have answer for this.

Comment: Yes, uniform convergence is enough.