Euler's Gamma function and convergence of an integral
I'm trying to calculate the following integral:
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\cos(x)dx$$
and I figured a way to do it would be to expand the cosine in its Taylor series, switch the integral and summation sign (which I believe I can do since both functions are sufficiently regular) and then add up the summation. Nonetheless, I get a divergent series, and I don't know where my mistake is (although I would say it is precisely in switching the integral and summation sign). My reasoning is as follows:
$$I=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\cos(x)dx = \int_0^\infty e^{-x}\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}dx$$
Now, I integrate before I add everything up:
$$I=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{2n}dx$$
Using Euler's Gamma function: $\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{z-1}dt$, I can easily identify $z=2n+1$. Therefore, I get:
$$I=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\Gamma(2n+1)$$
And since for natural numbers we have $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$, then I can write my expression as:
$$I=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}(2n)!$$
Canceling the factorials, I finally get:
$$I=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n$$
which is clearly divergent. Nonetheless, I have computed the integral numerically and I get 1/2. What am I doing wrong?

In general, you cannot just interchange the order of integration and summation. There are certain rules for that.

@Gary I thought I could do it if the integrand was a composition of sufficiently regular functions (i.e: elemental functions, as in this case)

That is not enough at all. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1335512 You will find that the problem is that $\mathrm{e}^{-x}\cosh(x)$ is not integrable on $(0,\infty)$.

See the link for the sum of your divergent series. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series

Another way to solve:
$$I=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\cos(x)dx=\Re\int_0^\infty e^{-(1-i)x}dx=-\Re\frac{e^{-(1-i)x}}{1-i}\Big\rvert_0^{+\infty}=\Re\frac1{1-i}=\frac12.$$

As stated in the comments, you cannot always change the order of integration and summation.
A much simpler way to calculate the integral is applying integration by parts twice. Doing so we get $$I=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\cos(x)dx=[e^{-x}\sin(x)]\Big\rvert_0^{+\infty}+\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\sin(x)dx=$$ $$0+ [-e^{-x}\cos(x)]\Big\rvert_0^{+\infty}-\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\cos(x)dx=1-I  $$
Which directly implies that $I=\dfrac{1}{2}$.
